# Laravel 5.7 - Spark API authentication session issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-spark

Just going to preface this question by saying that I'm diving back into Laravel after a while of not using it, it appears there are a lot of changes, and the current project in question is using A LOT of the baked in "Laravel Ecosystem"... so I could be missing some context here.

**The issue :** After upgrading from Laravel 5.6 to 5.7, auth-guarded API routes are busting because of session expiry, even immediately after logging in (prompting logout).

**The configuration :**

*/config/auth.php*

```
'guards' => ['api' => ['driver' => 'spark']]
```

*/routes/api.php*

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function () {
    // Routes in here are busting
}
```

*/app/Providers/SparkServiceProvider.php*

```
protected $usesApi = true; // yup
```

**Additional info :**

- The site uses the Socialite plugin for managing user authentication
- There are indeed `spark_token`'s in the request
- Vue client making the calls, getting status `401 Unauthorized` on the next page load after successfully authenticating via login form
- It was working perfectly fine before upgrading from Laravel 5.6 to 5.7

Any ideas? I've poured through the Laravel 5.7 release notes / upgrade guide, not finding any relevant info.

Comment: session expiry?  API routes don't normally have sessions.

Comment: From the outset the application is telling me the session has expired, most likely a default reaction to unauthorized calls.

Comment: @Meowts, perhaps the route being accessed is not within the "scope" of the token being issued?

Comment: @TJWeems I wasn't aware of token scopes, apparently that's a thing, but I can't find any definitions to do with that. What throws me off is that it's not using Passport, and there's a lot of boilerplate to sift through. Might need a sledgehammer.

Comment: @Meowts - did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Shane I'm afraid not, instead I jumped ship :-| :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked for me:

Add to `app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php`

```
    /**
     * Indicates if cookies should be serialized.
     * @var bool
     */
    protected static $serialize = false;
```

Then clear cookies from your browser, and retry logging in.